# Label from selected inputSelect Option returns Undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I have an `inputSelect` on a page with one option. The label for the Option displays "Name" and it's value is "Name__c".

Component:

```
<ui:inputSelect class="form-control" aura:id="testFields" />
```

I am setting the `inputSelect` values dynamically as such:

```
var opts = [];
opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: "Name", value: "Name__c:"});
inputsel.set("v.options", opts);
```

When I try to get the value from the selected option, I receive "Name__c", as I expect to.

When I try to get the label, I get `undefined`, despite the label showing in the UI correctly. What am I doing wrong?

JS Controller:

```
var inputSel = cmp.find("testFields");    
inputSel.get("v.value"); //Name__c
inputSel.get("v.label"); //undefined
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code? What's the value of `picklist`?Try `inputSel.get("v.value");`

Comment: @SE_User I have added a little more and changed the incorrect variable names, the `picklist` variable that you pointed out was in fact a mistake.